# Any way to fix this mp4 that was cut off during recording

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mplayer, mp4, video-conversion

I took a video with my Android phone but failed to press the Stop button properly. So my phone ran out of disk memory and the **Video App probably just cut off the file.**

After copying the file (size 2.1 GB) to my ubuntu desktop I tried to run it with `mplayer`. The output is:

```
MPlayer 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.4.0 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing 20190215_141432.mp4.
libavformat version 56.40.101 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f0685aced80]Protocol name not provided, cannot determine if input is local or a network protocol, buffers and access patterns cannot be configured optimally without knowing the protocol
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f0685aced80]Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709), 1920x1080): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
LAVF_header: av_find_stream_info() failed
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
VIDEO:  [H264]  1920x1080  24bpp  90000.000 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
 major_brand: mp42
 minor_version: 0
 compatible_brands: isommp42
 creation_time: 2019-02-15 14:06:39
Load subtitles in ./
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 56.60.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
V:   0.0   0/  0 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0 


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Is there any way to fix this? Maybe there is just some meta-data which needs to be corrected.

**I also tried this but output is the same:**

```
mplayer -lavfdopts analyzeduration=120 20190215_141432.mp4
```

**Then I tried to cut the video**

```
ffmpeg -probesize 1000M -analyzeduration 1000M 
    -i 20190215_141432.mp4 -pix_fmt yuvj420p 
    -ss 00:00:00 -c copy -t 00:05:30 new.mp4
```

But the output is about the same:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
[...]
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x182d380] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709), 1920x1080): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
20190215_141432.mp4: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20190215_141432.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2019-02-15 12:06:39
  Duration: 00:19:49.40, bitrate: 10308 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 10.94 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      creation_time   : 2019-02-15 12:06:39
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -180.00 degrees
[...]
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

Pls note that I specified the `pix_fmt, probesize` and `analyzeduration` but got as reply

> unspecified pixel format. Consider increasing the value for the
>   'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

Btw: I tried `pixel_format` also.

**My final attemp, so far, has been to use** `untrunc`. The output is:

```
Repair: 20190215_141432.mp4
Failed to parse atoms in truncated file
```

**Update on (edited) answer (by Fabby):**

I tried this

```
ffmpeg  -i 20190215_141432.mp4 -probesize 100M -analyzeduration 100M -map_metadata -1 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 512K new.mkv
```

(and played around with values like `1024M`, `2G`, `4G` and placing of parameters (as [suggested in here](https://superuser.com/questions/1181422/unable-to-parse-option-value-1-as-pixel-format-when-transcoding-mp4-to-mp4-us#comment1710631_1181422)) but output is essentially:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xc0c4a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709), 1920x1080): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
20190215_141432.mp4: could not find codec parameters
[...]
Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) specified for output file #0 (new.mkv) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
[...]
[buffer @ 0xc137e0] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
    Last message repeated 1 times
[buffer @ 0xc137e0] Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xc133e0] Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!
```

**I am going to lay this question to rest, now.**

> Reasons: It is dead simpe to cut videos, join videos - even roatate
>   videos using `ffmpeg/mencoder` or other tools. Cutting, joining,
>   rotating actions should (according to my understanding) re-arrange
>   meta-data in the first place.
>
> I this case, meta-data is there and valid (such as duration, format,
>   creation time...). So, why is repairing meta-data in this case that
>   difficult? Extremely annoying is commands output, claiming that pixel
>   format would not have been specified and so on....
>
> After all. I thought repairing this video just needs a valuable hint
>   or some magic canonical tool but after all, my life doesn't depend on
>   it.

Comment: First of all, what research have you done? This is quite a common question in different forums. Have you tried `ffmpeg -i  yuor.mp4`?

Comment: @MatsK Updated the question. I tried a lot more but because outcome is roughly the same I don't want to paste it all here. And it is quite difficult to search for that topic cos there are a lot of different cases why an mp4 might become corrupted.

Comment: Have you tried tackling the problem from a binary perspective yet, with hexeditor for example? What looks broken to me is the header, hence the untrunc error.

Comment: Could you please post the output of `xxd 20190215_141432.mp4|head -20` . I may be able to tell you which values need to be edited to restore the header.

Comment: **Würgspaß** try the above ---^ maybe @BarBar1234 has some nifty hacking trick...

Comment: There's [untrunc](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc), but you need a non-truncated video file to copy the meta data structures from (which should be ready for you to make/get). Have you `ffprobe`-ed it (share output with pastebin.com), also, try playing with VLC as it seems to handle things other apps can't.

Comment: @pbhj I ran untrunc with a working video. Error msg see above. As for VLC: `mp4 demux error: cannot create chunks index`. `ffprobe`: Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709), 1920x1080): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

Comment: @BarBar1234 see edit.

Comment: I realise that it is a reasonably big file but are you able to post it somewhere online?

Comment: Related: [Corrupt MP4 recording interrupted](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/18523/1760) (also see additional related links in comment to linked question).

Comment: @Fabby I am not sure which edit you would like me to concentrate on particularly

Comment: @BarBar1234 the one that contains the [header](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1118725/8) you asked for completely at the end...  **;-)**  I'll upvote your answer if you ping me here as you seem to have some magic that I'm not aware of...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, but with .MP4 files you need both the header and the footer of the file to make it playable, so fully transcoding (and  not just copying) ***might*** make it readable:

```
ffmpeg -i 20190215_141432.mp4 -probesize 100M -analyzeduration 100M -map_metadata -1 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 512K 20190215_141432.mkv
```

If that doesn't help, the contents are truly lost as the footer cannot be reconstructed from the data you've got.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please note, that you've got typo in your answer. Should be `-strict`. Cannot edit it as editing needs at least six characters.

Comment: It's not encouraged!  **;-)**  Look at what BarBar1234 is asking: he wants the output of the first bits of your file and might be able to fix it.

Comment: Yeh, but you are closer, I think. the only problem is this ` Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.` Why not not try a lil bit and collect the bounty?

Comment: The `pix_fmt to value -1` is the input filter being set as "unknown", it shows up in the question in the mplayer output as `Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709), 1920x1080): unspecified pixel format`. The fix is to `Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options`. Similarly with ffmpeg output, you can try the [solution in this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1181422/unable-to-parse-option-value-1-as-pixel-format-when-transcoding-mp4-to-mp4-us#comment1710631_1181422) that worked for them.

Comment: @Würgspaß see [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1126277/revisions)

Comment: @Würgspaß I am confused why you actually added and then removed the 20 bits of the file as seen in the edits. I have reverse engineered broken files before and typically this is where the magic lies, or at the very least it is the first step that allows you to use various additional tools. I am going to proceed as if what I see in the edits is the header excerpt.

Comment: Yup.  That one!  @BarBar1234  **:-)**

Comment: Ok, great. Already working on it. However, I have a few additional (some meta) questions. I am going to include them as the beginning of my answer post which will not have an answer from the get go, but I will update as I go, so I hope moderators allow some leeway until we extract what we need. While a copy of the broken file in question would be preferred, I have full respect for people's privacy and completely understand how someone might want to both repair such video file, yet also not feel at ease about disseminating multiple copies of such file to strangers known only by their username.

Comment: @BarBar1234 better ask more questions in the comments then.  Mods and reviewers don't like partial answers. **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯** Also: ask the user if they want to divulge their identity and share the file with you outside this site...

Comment: Thanks @Fabby Understood. I had a fairly intricate answer/explanation written already with how this problem can be approached , I will definitely included it in the "answer" at a later final stage. Questions in the comments below.

Comment: Question 1: You mentioned that your broken file is 2.1GB. Does this make sense to you i.e. given the resolution and frame rate this size is reasonable or is it way off? The reason I ask is because to this day, I have two exactly identical video streams that I worked on way back in the day, yet the good file is 3mb and the broken one is 1.5Gb.

Question 2:  How did you record this file exactly? I am going to assume that by the Video App you mean the recording function of the built-in Camera. Can you provide the name and model of your phone?

Comment: **Question** **2** :  How did you create this file exactly? I am going to assume that by the Video App you mean the recording function of the built-in Camera. Can you provide the name and model of your phone, as well as the name of the OS they operate on?

Comment: @Würgspaß   See above ---^